# How to optimize a library for tree-shaking via webpack 4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, tree-shaking

I'm trying to learn webpack 4 better and expirimenting with tree-shaking on a private library.  I have a pretty minimal config

```
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin')
const path = require('path')
const argv = require('yargs').argv

let pkg = argv.pkg || 'forms'

module.exports = {
  entry: `./src/${pkg}`,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')
  },
  mode: 'production',
  node: {
    global: false,
    process: false,
    __filename: false,
    __dirname: false,
    Buffer: false,
    setImmediate: false
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin([path.resolve(__dirname, './dist')]),
    new BundleAnalyzerPlugin({
      openAnalyzer: false
    })
  ],
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJSPlugin({
        uglifyOptions: {
          compress: {
            sequences: false,
            properties: false,
            conditionals: false,
            comparisons: false,
            evaluate: false,
            booleans: false,
            loops: false,
            hoist_funs: false,
            hoist_vars: false,
            if_return: false,
            join_vars: false,
            keep_fnames: true,
            keep_classnames: true
          },
          output: { beautify: true },
          mangle: false
        }
      })
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a single src file that looks like this.

```
// prettier-ignore
import { BareInput } from '@entrata/forms'

console.log(BareInput)
```

I simplified my library to only export two components (BareInput, BareEmailInput) and as you can see, i'm only importing one of them in this test webpack app. It seems like tree shaking should work here but I still see BareEmailInput in my bundle.

My library bundle:

```
import 'date-fns/format';
import isEmail from 'validator/lib/isEmail';
import 'validator/lib/isURL';
import 'date-fns/add_minutes';
import 'date-fns/is_past';
import 'date-fns/get_year';
import 'date-fns/get_days_in_month';
import 'date-fns/is_after';
import 'date-fns/is_before';
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

var _extends = Object.assign || function (target) {
  for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    var source = arguments[i];

    for (var key in source) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) {
        target[key] = source[key];
      }
    }
  }

  return target;
};

var objectWithoutProperties = function (obj, keys) {
  var target = {};

  for (var i in obj) {
    if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) continue;
    if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue;
    target[i] = obj[i];
  }

  return target;
};

var REQUIRED = 'This field is required';

var required = function required(_ref) {
  var value = _ref.value,
      required = _ref.required;

  if (required && !value) {
    return REQUIRED;
  } else {
    return '';
  }
};

var email = function email(_ref3) {
  var required = _ref3.required,
      _ref3$value = _ref3.value,
      value = _ref3$value === undefined ? '' : _ref3$value;

  var trimmed = value.replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|\s$/g, '');

  return trimmed ? isEmail(trimmed) ? '' : 'Please enter a valid email' : required ? REQUIRED : '';
};

/** A primitive input component. */
var BareInput = React.forwardRef(function (_ref, ref) {
  var active = _ref.active,
      invalid = _ref.invalid,
      rest = objectWithoutProperties(_ref, ['active', 'invalid']);
  return (// eslint-disable-line
    React.createElement('input', _extends({ ref: ref, 'aria-invalid': invalid }, rest))
  );
});

BareInput.validate = required;

BareInput.propTypes = {
  /** Disables the input. */
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  /** A unique identifier for the input. */
  id: PropTypes.string,
  /** `true` if the input is in error state and has been touched. */
  invalid: PropTypes.bool,
  /** A name for the component. */
  name: PropTypes.string,
  /** Handler for blur event */
  onBlur: PropTypes.func,
  /** handler for change event */
  onChange: PropTypes.func,
  /** handler for focus event */
  onFocus: PropTypes.func,
  /** Input placeholder. */
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  /** If the input is required. Used for validation. */
  required: PropTypes.bool,
  /** The input type. */
  type: PropTypes.string,
  /** The value of the input. */
  value: PropTypes.string
};

BareInput.defaultProps = {
  type: 'text',
  value: ''
};

/** A primitive input with email validation. */
var BareEmailInput = function BareEmailInput(props) {
  return React.createElement(BareInput, props);
};

BareEmailInput.validate = email;

BareEmailInput.propTypes = {
  /** Add class to input. */
  className: PropTypes.string,
  /** Disable the Input. */
  disabled: PropTypes.bool,
  /** Required Id for input. */
  id: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  /** `true` when the input is in error state and has been touched. */
  invalid: PropTypes.string,
  /** Name for input. */
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  /** Handler for blur event. */
  onBlur: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  /** handler for change event. */
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  /** handler for focus event. */
  onFocus: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  /** Input Placeholder. */
  placeholder: PropTypes.string,
  /** Is the input required? */
  required: PropTypes.bool,
  /** Input value. */
  value: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

BareEmailInput.defaultProps = {
  value: ''
};

export { BareInput, BareEmailInput };
//# sourceMappingURL=forms.es.js.map
```

And, my generated webpack bundle:

```
!function(modules) {
    // React and webpack stuff removed for brevity...
    var REQUIRED = "This field is required";
    var BareInput = react_default.a.forwardRef(function(_ref, ref) {
        _ref.active;
        var invalid = _ref.invalid, rest = function(obj, keys) {
            var target = {};
            for (var i in obj) {
                if (keys.indexOf(i) >= 0) continue;
                if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, i)) continue;
                target[i] = obj[i];
            }
            return target;
        }(_ref, [ "active", "invalid" ]);
        return react_default.a.createElement("input", _extends({
            ref: ref,
            "aria-invalid": invalid
        }, rest));
    });
    BareInput.validate = function required(_ref) {
        var value = _ref.value, required = _ref.required;
        if (required && !value) return REQUIRED; else return "";
    };
    BareInput.propTypes = {
        disabled: prop_types_default.a.bool,
        id: prop_types_default.a.string,
        invalid: prop_types_default.a.bool,
        name: prop_types_default.a.string,
        onBlur: prop_types_default.a.func,
        onChange: prop_types_default.a.func,
        onFocus: prop_types_default.a.func,
        placeholder: prop_types_default.a.string,
        required: prop_types_default.a.bool,
        type: prop_types_default.a.string,
        value: prop_types_default.a.string
    };
    BareInput.defaultProps = {
        type: "text",
        value: ""
    };
    var forms_es_BareEmailInput = function BareEmailInput(props) {
        return react_default.a.createElement(BareInput, props);
    };
    forms_es_BareEmailInput.validate = function email(_ref3) {
        var required = _ref3.required, _ref3$value = _ref3.value;
        var trimmed = (void 0 === _ref3$value ? "" : _ref3$value).replace(/^[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|[\s\uFEFF\xA0]+|\s$/g, "");
        return trimmed ? isEmail_default()(trimmed) ? "" : "Please enter a valid email" : required ? REQUIRED : "";
    };
    forms_es_BareEmailInput.propTypes = {
        className: prop_types_default.a.string,
        disabled: prop_types_default.a.bool,
        id: prop_types_default.a.string.isRequired,
        invalid: prop_types_default.a.string,
        name: prop_types_default.a.string.isRequired,
        onBlur: prop_types_default.a.func.isRequired,
        onChange: prop_types_default.a.func.isRequired,
        onFocus: prop_types_default.a.func.isRequired,
        placeholder: prop_types_default.a.string,
        required: prop_types_default.a.bool,
        value: prop_types_default.a.string.isRequired
    };
    forms_es_BareEmailInput.defaultProps = {
        value: ""
    };
    console.log(BareInput);
} ]);
```

So I have a few questions, why does BareEmailInput still exist in my webpack bundle? and why does it appear to be handled differently than BareInput? (ie: why forms_es_BareEmailInput rather than just BareEmailInput?)

I have searched for side effects but I do not see any and i do have `sideEffects: false` in my package.json for my library.

Using webpack v4.16.5

Comment: treeshaking only happens when mode=production. Try adding mode directly to cli too, because your result bundle is not minified neither uglified, so it is not in production mode.

Comment: @PlayMa256 It is in production mode. I am beautifying and not mangling the output as shown in my webpack config.  I do this so that I can more easily analyze the output. If I remove those settings, it definitely minifies/uglifies.

Comment: its worth creating a small reproducible example and drop an issue on their repo

Comment: Also, note that `React.forwardRef` breaks tree-shaking. The best way to address this would be a Babel plugin that adds a `/*#__PURE__*/` comment immediately before `React.forwardRef`. I'm planning to open an issue about this for `@babel/preset-react`, since it doesn't look like anyone has addressed this yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try to refractor so you just have one reference to your object outside. for eg after defining the 'BareInput' object, you are attaching properties to it. This will confuse webpack and it will not treeshake. What you need to do is to put the object and and its properties inside a single function. And this function or class should not have any properties. Give it a try.